# Why is Bazel version 0.26.1 not working on Windows? 'bazel' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel, msys2, windows-11

I am trying to use Bazel to install a TensorFlow 1.x model on my Windows 11 system, but I am running into issues with Bazel version 0.26.1. I followed the instructions provided on the Bazel website to download and install the correct version of Bazel, added the necessary directories to my system path, and set the BAZEL_SH variable to the path of my MSYS2 Bash installation. However, when I try to run 'bazel version' in the command prompt, I get the error "'bazel' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

I have checked that the Bazel executable file is located in the correct directory and that all the necessary directories have been added to my system path correctly. I have also tried restarting my system, but I still encounter the same error.

Is there anything else I need to do to get Bazel version 0.26.1 working on my Windows 11 system? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

As mentioned above, I added the location of the Bazel.exe file to the system path, and I added both a user variable and a system variable that set the BAZEL_SH value to the MSYS2 bash.exe file. I tried both without the other to see if that was the issue, however moving the bash variable did nothing. I expected that when I ran "bazel version" in cmd, I would get "0.26.1". However I got the error: "'bazel' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." Here is the page that I got most of my information from: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.26.0/install-windows.html and here is the page where I downloaded the .exe file for bazel from: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/tag/0.26.1. I used the bazel-0.26.1-windows-x86_64.exe file and changed the name to just bazel.exe like the page suggested. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: MSYS2 doesn't respect the system-wide PATH by default. Confirm by doing `echo $PATH`. `msys2_shell.cmd -full-path` does.